# Dynamically update a plot of a function that evaluates slowly

Tags: plotting, dynamic

Suppose I have a time-consuming function `fun[x]`. I would like to see the plot between, say `{x, 0, 1}`. I would like to watch each individual points being plotted as the recursion goes on.

I will use a `sin` function with a `pause` to emulate a slow function. In reality, suppose we are plotting a function which is very cost-expensive, thus we want to minimize the total points where the function is evaluated on.

```
Dynamic2DPlot[fun_, recursion_] := 
  Block[{},
    plt = {};
    list = {{}};
    Do[
      list = Flatten[{Append[#, 0] & /@ list, Append[#, 1] & /@ list}, 1], 
      {recursion}];
    samples = FromDigits[{#, 0}, 2] & /@ list;
    For[j = 1, j <= Length[samples], j++,
      coord = samples[[j]];
      z = fun[coord];
      Pause[0.1];
      plt = Append[plt, {coord, z}];];]
```

`samples` is just a list of coordinates in the executing order.

> `{0, 1/2, 1/4, 3/4, 1/8, 5/8, 3/8, 7/8, 1/16, 9/16, 5/16, 13/16, 3/16, 
>   11/16, 7/16, 15/16, ...}`

Now this works perfectly, as `plt` is a global variable

```
Dynamic[ListLinePlot[SortBy[plt, First], Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]]
Dynamic2DPlot[Sin[4*#] &, 4]
```

[image]

However, putting these two lines in `Block` or `Module` will not work, as the Dynamic part ceases to show up.
Ideally I'm looking for a way to create a package, where I can call in another notebook like this:

```
Dynamic2DPlot[fun[x], {x,0,1}, recursion->5]
```

And it will behave just like a normal `ListLinePlot` but will update the graph once a new datapoint is calculated.

Answer (score 6):

This might not be an answer because I'm not sure what you're after exactly.  It might be [`CellPrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellPrint.html) and [`CellExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellExpression.html) as shown in the proof-of-concept example below.

```
slow[x_] := (Pause[0.1]; x (1 - x));
Module[{pts = {}, y, f},
 f[x_?NumericQ] := y = slow[x];
 CellPrint@ExpressionCell[
   Dynamic@ListLinePlot[pts, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1/4}}],
   "Output"];
 Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 5, 
  EvaluationMonitor :> (pts = Sort@Append[pts, {x, y}])];
 ]
```

[image]

In this case the plotting is driven by `Plot`, which has automatic recursive subdivision.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I admit I am not sure about what you trying to do, but the following much simpler code does the same thing as your code does only in a more robust way.

```
Dynamic2DPlot[fun_, steps_] :=
  Do[
    plot =
      ListLinePlot[{#, fun[#]} & /@ Range[0, 1, 1/2^j],
        Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}];
    Pause[.5],
    {j, steps}]

plot = Null; Dynamic[plot]
Dynamic2DPlot[Sin[4 #] &, 4];
```

[image: plot]

Whether or not this can serve as the basis of something you can make into a package would more information on how you plan to use the package to decide. However, I believe this to be a far better basis for further exploration of the problem than the code you have posted.

Comment: Thank you, Goldberg. I'm sorry that I didn't make it clear. My goal was to visualize the subdivision as the `plot` is going on. The `pause` function is just to emulate a slow function, not just for an animation purpose. So it would be better to reuse the value of a calculated point. Thank you for your help anyway!